# How do I make an Image into a hyperlink?

Tags: android, image, canvas, hyperlink, bitmap

Looking through the Android API I come across Bitmaps which I think I need here. I have a JPG that I want to be on the screen that when clicked on, opens up a browser to a certain webpage. How do I go about do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("www.google.com")));
            }
        });
```

and don't forget to add the Internet Permission..

Answer (score 1):

```
imageObject.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

          WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
          myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
        }
    });
```

Also edit android-manifest.xml and set USER-PERMISSIONS so that your app can use internet.

Answer (score 1):

use click [`Event Listeners`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) for this.

```
image.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //perform action
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setonclicklistner` method for this...

```
image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                // ur code to open the browser
            }
        });
```